# Nested UL Columns will not float left unless I set container width explicitly

Tags: html, css

This is what I want my dropdown to look like, key css listed below:

"#nav .flyout > li { float:left; }

"#nav .flyout.fourCol { width:900px; }"

http://jsfiddle.net/t7esz/  (this works)

But, when I set "#nav .flyout.fourCol { width:auto; }" all of the lis collapse down below each other. It's like unless I explicitly set the containers width they won't float left or display inline.

http://jsfiddle.net/sumcA/2/ (this doesn't work, I want to be able to use width auto here!)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

`Css`

```
.list { width: 980px; height: 39px; background-color: #878787; }
.list ul { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.list ul li { 
    float: left; 
    padding: 10px; 
    font-size: 14px; 
    background-color: #3c3c3c; 
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

`Html`

```
<div class="list">
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>No width set</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And it will look like this:

```
http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/2721/noautoulli.png
```